# Upload static resource to Amazon s3 server using maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload static content from my project repository to **Amazon S3 (Simple Storage Service)** which includes all the content enclosed inside **src/main/webapp**.For which i need to use **maven plugin** to automate such resource upload on build time.

While researching i stumble upon few such maven plugins notably :

1. **s3-upload-maven-plugin** (see documentation [here](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/s3-upload-maven-plugin))
        - it only supports single file upload at a time
2. **s3-static-uploader** (see documentation [here](https://github.com/pentasoft/s3-static-uploader))-an exciting prospect to look forward,however minimal functionality available
3. **aws-parent**(see documentation [here](https://github.com/aro1976/aws-parent) ) -no official maven plugin released but shares proximity with s3-static-uploader and i was unable to make it work
4. **jetS3t**(see release documentation [here](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.html))

I have tried all these plugins and each time i fail to achieve my goal.

The close i came to achieve my goal was while using **s3-static-uploader** and my pom looks like

```xml
 <plugin>
        <groupId>io.pst.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3-static-uploader-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <accessKey>${aws.accessKey}</accessKey>
            <secretKey>${aws.secretKey}</secretKey>
            <bucketName>${aws.bucketName}</bucketName>
            <refreshExpiredObjects>true</refreshExpiredObjects>
            <includes>
                <include>
                    <bind>
                        <!-- Could be path expressions or reg. expressions -->
                        <pattern>%regex[([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp|tif|pdf|swf|eps))$)]</pattern>
                        <metadataId>static</metadataId>
                    </bind>
                </include>
                <include>
                    <bind>
                        <pattern>%regex[([^\s]+(\.(?i)(css|js))$)]</pattern>
                        <metadataId>volatile</metadataId>
                    </bind>
                </include>
                <include>
                    <bind>
                        <!-- Extension less files -->
                        <pattern>%regex[^[^.]+$]</pattern>
                        <metadataId>volatile-naked</metadataId>
                    </bind>
                </include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>WEB-INF/.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
            <metadatas>
                <metadata>
                    <id>static</id>
                    <cacheControl>public</cacheControl>
                    <contentEncoding>plain</contentEncoding>
                    <contentType>text/html</contentType>
                    <cannedAcl>PublicRead</cannedAcl>
                </metadata>
                <metadata>
                    <id>static-longlived</id>
                    <cacheControl>public</cacheControl>
                    <contentEncoding>plain</contentEncoding>
                           <contentType>text/html</contentType>
                    <cannedAcl>PublicRead</cannedAcl>
                </metadata>
                <metadata>
                    <id>volatile</id>
                    <cacheControl>private</cacheControl>
                    <contentEncoding>plain</contentEncoding>
                    <contentType>text/html</contentType>
                    <cannedAcl>PublicRead</cannedAcl>
                </metadata>
                <metadata>
                    <id>volatile-naked</id>
                    <cacheControl>private</cacheControl>
                    <contentEncoding>plain</contentEncoding>
                    <contentType>text/html</contentType>
                    <cannedAcl>PublicRead</cannedAcl>
                </metadata>
            </metadatas>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>upload</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

But on *maven install* only one file is uploaded and it shows build failure with following message for next file:

> Failed to execute goal
>   io.pst.mojo:s3-static-uploader-plugin:1.1:upload (default-cli) on
>   project sbworkbenchnavigation-portlet: cannot process file
>   /home/pawal/sbworkbench/portlets/sbworkbenchnavigation-portlet/src/main/webapp/css/main.css:
>   Access Denied ->

And on next *maven install* it shows same error for the next file.And after all files are iterated in same process the build shows success message.

**Question :**

1. Am i doing anything wrong?.I have followed the plugin documentation
   precisely(*i think*).
2. Are there any other maven plugins that i could use to upload static content to Amazion s3 server?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution and decided to fork my own =)

It is based on s3-upload-maven-plugin (I use multiple executions to allow multiple files).
Check it out on: https://github.com/moacyrricardo/s3-upload-maven-plugin

Answer (score 3):

The same appears achievable by combination of s3-wagon extension and wagon plugin:

.m2/settings.xml

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>aws-release</id>
      <username>ASFFDSFDSFDSFDSFSFDF</username>
      <password>Hmasdflaskdjflksdjflaskdjflasjdflkasjdfl</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

pom.xml

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.kuali.maven.wagons</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>deploy-release</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>upload</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <serverId>aws-release</serverId>
                    <url>s3://${bucket}/releases/</url>
                    <fromDir>${project.build.directory}</fromDir>
                    <toDir>${project.version}</toDir>
                    <includes>
                        ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar,
                        ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.dmg,
                        ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-shaded.jar,
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</build>
```